# Django ImageField serializer field is None when accessed in a View

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a serializer for image uploads and want to access the image in a view when uploaded to that endpoint.

*serializer*

```
class AccountInvestigationFileUploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField()
```

*view*

```
class AccountInvestigationFileUploadView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = AccountInvestigationFileUploadSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=request.data)
```

However when I try accessing the serializer data in the view it is None.

```sh
> serializer
AccountInvestigationFileUploadSerializer(context={'request': <rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/api/v1/investigation/upload/'>}, data=<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['TiblXu6wmpaE7qQJ10eneBEV1vRKRBi7GkwqIZdEhlbu0BfYFM3qAqY4235gv6z3NwNi'], 'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Screen Shot 2021-09-12 at 12.57.25 PM.png (image/png)>]}>):
    sketch_id = CharField(max_length=255)
    request_id = CharField(max_length=255)
    image = ImageField()

> serializer.data
{'image': None}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of DRF you are using?

Comment: drf version 3.12.2

Comment: Show AccountInvestigationFileUploadSerializer.Meta parameters - `fields` attribute.